# Intel-microcode Package on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, package-management

I saw the intel-microcode in the ubuntu repositories and was wondering if it was worth installing on my Yorkfield-6M based system. If so, what are the benefits from this package?

Answer (score 2):

Microcode is update of processor of runtime. If any problems are found in hardware they may be fixed by such software update.